# Make an entry to Survey list using workflow when an item is added to custom list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, custom-list, survey-list

I have a 'Title'(single line of text) column in a Custom List and a 'Question'(choice) column in a Survey List. My requirement is, whenever an item is added to Custom list, its 'Title' should be added to the 'Question' as a choice in the Survey list . Is it possible to achieve this using SharePoint 2013 designer workflow or by any other means ?

Comment: Is it that you want to add the 'Title' field of every new item added in the custom list to get added as a new choice to the 'Question' (choice column)   of the survey list?

Comment: Yes ! @mohdtahir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That could be done using a lookup column.

**Step 1**

Create your custom list and add few items to it.

**Step 2**

Create a column in the survey list with name as 'Question' and select the datatype of the column as lookup, as descriptive in the following picture:

[image]

Now set the 'Get Information from' as your custom list and 'In this column' as the Title field. Now you will find all the items present in the custom list in the Question choice field, avaliable for selection. Also whenever a new item gets addeds in the custom list these choices will get updated automatically.

Comment: It was this easy and I was thinking a about workflows and all. Thanks you @mohdtahir